# Fully Associative Cache

Tags: c++, caching, memory, cpu-architecture

I am to trying to figure a problem for hw, where i need to see how many cache misses occur for the following nested loop

```
for i=0; i < 32 ; i++
   for j=0; j < 32; j++
      sum += arr[i][j];
```

I have a fully associative cache which has 16 cache lines, where each cache line can store 32 words. The cache is initially empty and arr[0][0] maps to the first cache line

Now according to my understanding, there will be a total of 32 misses.Initially when a request is made the cache is empty so it counts as a miss and according to a fully associative cache all the blocks get populated and then the LRU is applied.

I am a bit confused here,could use some guidance here

Comment: If `arr` is a normal multidimensional array (and not an array of pointers or something), then your loop is just a sequential read of the memory block.  Assuming i, j, and sum don't spill to memory, cache associativity makes no diff here; even a direct-mapped cache would perform identically.

Comment: Yes the arr is multidimensional array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming an integer is stored in a word.**

Lets start with the 1<sup>st</sup> memory access ie. `arr[0][0]`. It will result in a miss which comes under compulsory miss. This will bring 32 integers in to the cache. **To our benefit we are going to access those exact memory locations in our further accesses.** Which is from `arr[0][0]` to `arr[0][31]`.

Now when we access `arr[1][0]` we are accessing the 33rd location and this is not in our cache. So this is again a miss.

**In general for every 32 values that you access you will  have a miss.** Please not that this is only for the kind of loop that you have showed :

> ```
> for i=0; i < 32 ; i++
>    for j=0; j < 32; j++
>       sum += arr[i][j];
> ```

Here the memory access is continuous. Further as @Peter Cordes said in the comments, the fully associative cache will behave in the exact same way as a direct mapped cache in your particular case.

Comment: The question doesn't say integers.  They could be word-size `float`s, or really anything else.  Your assumption that each array element is a word is probably what was intended though, even though the question doesn't rule out two-word `double`, or 4-per-word `char`, or (since this is C++) a large class with an overloaded `operator++`.

Comment: @PeterCordes yea. I have assumed that the element size is a word. But the idea I gave would be sufficient enough to calculate for any size data

Comment: yes, of course :)  I think I mostly just wanted to complain about the question quality some more.